# jquery row hover and click events

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to highlight a row on hover which works fine for me. At the same time, I want to highlight the hovered row when it is clicked. Below is my code till now:

```
        $(".simplehighlight").hover(function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
        });
```

If I make the click event same as above, its not working.

```
        $(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
        });
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you click on another row? Should the previously clicked row stay highlighted?

Comment: no. The current clicked row should be highlighted, and the current row should be highlighted even when hovering over other row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Here is a much better version using CSS classes:

```
$(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    // comment the following line if you don't want to dehighlight other rows
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});

$(".simplehighlight").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
}, function() {
    $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '');
});
```

Where the CSS is:

```
.simplehighlight {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clicked {
    background-color: #ffdc87;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gRSXZ/1/)

---

**Old answer:** *Works but unnecessary complex.*

`click` only accepts one callback, not two. You could use `data` to check whether row is clicked or not:

```
$(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    $(this).data('clicked', !clicked);
    if(clicked) {
        $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
    }
    else {
        $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
    }
});
```

Then in order to **not** change the caller on `mouseleave`, check the `clicked` value:

```
$(".simplehighlight").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
},
function() {
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
    }
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BApKM/)

Comment: @Felix Kling: I got this working, but can I dehighlight one row when other row is clicked?

Comment: @user508518: See my updated answer. Using CSS classes is a much better approach. Just comment out the line `($this).siblings()` if you **don't** want do dehighlight other rows.

Comment: @Felix King: The click method is not working for me though it works in your demo.

Comment: @user508518: What do you mean with *not working*? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Felix King: The click function is not triggered at all. The hover works fine

Comment: @Felix King: The click function is triggered but the toggleClass is not applied. The hover works fine

Comment: @Felix King:I got it work with the code below. Let me know if that looks good  $(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
    $(this).children().addClass('clicked');
    $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('clicked');
   });

Comment: And other problem is, whatever solution I employ, both hover and click functions are slow in IE8. Is there a reason for this? For hover, it takes some milliseconds to catch up with the cursor, and with click, it takes around two seconds.

Comment: Ok. this is what I observed. toggleClass was not working because the children have a class already asscoiated with them. And the click and hover are slow because of there are large number of children. but it works very fast in firefox though

Answer (score 2):

If you want to de-highlight each row after clicking another, you could do something like this:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
    $(this).siblings().children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DwAdU/3/)

---

Using tbody:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function(){
    $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
    $(this).siblings().children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DwAdU/4/)

Comment: it highlights all the rows and columns. I am using thead and tbody in my table.

Comment: it works in your demo, but in my case, I am using thead and tbody, and it makes the border of each row and column to change colors, instead of the selected row

Answer (score 0):

i don' think is this valid

```
$(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
        });
```

change to

```
$(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');

        });
```

Comment: @user , your intial code is wrong , but i thought parts of it is working ,itshould be pretty simple , i will get you jsfiddle demo wait

Answer (score 0):

unlike .hover() .click() takes a single callback function .. see .toggle() instead... or you can use a css class to keep track of states - see these examples: http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-manipulating-element-classes/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

CSS:

```
.highlight { background-color: #ffdc87 }
```

JS:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $('tr').children().removeClass('highlight')
    $(this).children().addClass('highlight');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W3sZS/1/