# jquery slow when using children() with rows

Tags: jquery

Recently I asked a question on SO regarding changing row background color on click and hover using jquery.  Below is the link to it, and I implemented the solution marked as answer. The problem is when I am having lot of rows, the hover as well as click takes a lot of time. I am using IE8 with latest version of jquery. Below is the link to question

[jquery row hover and click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472715/jquery-row-hover-and-click-events)

Here is the code I implemented:

http://jsfiddle.net/EPUrh/

if you hover and click, its working and its fast for less rows, but if there are lot of rows/columns, it gets really slow and sometimes throws an error if I want to stop the script. When I compare the same in Firefox, it very fast. I have problem with this only in IE8. Can any one suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: It could be Internet Explorer's implementation of JavaScript slowing this down. How many rows are we talking? I made 300 rows and it's *instantaneous* with Google Chrome.

Comment: @Victor: You're probably right, but whether it is fast or not, there's a lot more work being done than needed since it is attempting to `removeClass` from *all* children of *all* rows except one, when there's only one row that needs to be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `click` handler, add a class to the `<tr>` that was clicked so when it comes time to remove the class on its `.children()`, you can target that specific row.

```
  $(".simplehighlight").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('wasClicked').children().addClass('clicked');

           // Get the sibling <tr> with the class "wasClicked"
           //   and remove that class, and the "clicked" class from  its children
        $(this).siblings('.wasClicked').removeClass('wasClicked')
                                       .children().removeClass('clicked');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding class to the parent has improved the performance a lot. Can you also tell me why adding css directly to children() does not work with click but works with hover: Like below:  $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');

Comment: @user508518 - because when you mouse out of the area - your "mouse out" event of  the `.hover()` will set the background color back to `''`

Answer (score 1):

Some random comments that may help:

You could use `tr.clicked td` as your css selector then apply the "clicked" class to the row instead of each individual table cell...  It would probably be much faster than needing to query all of the cells in the table.  [Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/mHRF3/) of how much cleaner it can be when you rely upon the CSS to handle the "children" portion that for you.

Also, instead of `.siblings().children()` try `.parent().find('td').not($this.children())` -- that would end up using `getElementsByTagName` as opposed to having to call `childNodes` on all the `tr` and then append those lists to each other...

Also - anytime you are working on performance issues like this, try running some sample code through [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) - it will help you test two different methods `.parent().find('td')` vs `.siblings().children()` for instance [this test](http://jsperf.com/parent-find-vs-sibilings-children) shows that the `siblings().children()` method is ~ 78% slower than `.parent().find('td').not()` when using chrome, 38% slower in safari.  I don't have IE8, but I imagine you would see significant improvement using that method.

There are a few good tips on [this blog post](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/) about performance of selectors, etc.  Pay very close attention to the **Bonus Tip – Storing jQuery results for later** section.

Comment: Thanks for information. for firefox 3.6.1, siblings children is little bit faster than parent.find, and for IE8, it throws an error to stop the script.

Comment: The IE8 I tested on gave me 2 ops/sec for .siblings().children() and 249 for .parent().find('td').not()

Comment: And so far --- firefox is the only browser .parent().find('td') has been slower...